# NullPointerException on toCTFont() method from ApachePOI

Tags: nullpointerexception, apache-poi

When trying to use the method getFontOfFormattingRun() from ApachePOI 3.13, a NullPointerException in some cases. Which would be the cause?

Comment: Is the object you're calling it on null perhaps? Any chance you could post some code to show the context of your NPE?

Comment: The CT-classes often have methods isXXXSet(), which allows to check for null before actually accessing the members, maybe you are hitting one of those here...